# How can I make an Adobe Flash / AIR application that reads from a txt file on a website and prints the text on screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is the idea:

- Read the contents of a txt file (http://www.myexample.com/helloworld.txt).
- Display the context of the TXT file on the screen.

I have read in some places and tried doing that with URLLoader but I failed...
 Can someone point me out on how to do it properly or provide me a simple script that does that?

Comment: _"...Tried doing that with URLLoader but I failed"_ What error does the compiler give you? Are you saying the loading itself failed or just that you're not sure how to add text to screen (you need a `textField` object to display). PS: If you want a solution faster then show your code that you tried and someone can guide you. Use [edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65646873/edit) to update your question.

Comment: If you're using flash in a local system to load web content, theres a security feature that blocks URLLoader from loading outside of local system, this is to prevent the plugin from loading malicious codes. To get around that, you can use a PHP proxy, simply google 'flash php proxy'. So instead of flash to web, you need flash to php to web. The php script is local so it bypasses that security feature.

Comment: It simply can not get the file at all. I compiled it to work on Android using Adobe AIR.
I used segments from an example from the manual and added my own stuff later.
Maybe I am failing on reading the contents of the TXT or maybe I am failing on downloading the TXT... One of both.